# Pass a specific time with today's date as a value to the input field in Informatica Cloud

Tags: parameter-passing, informatica, informatica-cloud

There is a mapping task which has a input field, the value provided to the field should be today's date and time is `18:00:00.000000000`. What is the formula to build this one?

Suppose the current month is 9, it should be passed as `09`. Same with the date, if the date is a single digit, 0 should be appended in the last.

The expected output for today is :
`09/24/2021 18:00:00.000000000`

The formula to build this value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you use this ?

```
to_char(sysdate,'MM/DD/YYYY') || '18:00:00.000000000'
```

Pls note this will produce a string.
If you want a datetime, pls convert this to datetime using `to_date(above_st, format)`

Comment: Used something similar to this one. I think what you wrote is Pwc version. IICS is a bit similar to this one. `date:toChar(fn:current-dateTime(), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS')`